# Creating instance of model in controller returns nil for id and timestamp Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm currently trying to create a `photo` in the controller. However, the instance is not being saved. I'm passing the correct parameters but not sure why is not being saved.

```
 18: def create
    19:   @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
 => 20:   binding.pry
    21:   if @photo.save
    22:     redirect_to @photo
    23:   else
    24:     render "new"
    25:   end
    26: end

[1] pry(#<PhotosController>)> Photo.new(photo_params)
=> #<Photo:0x00007fefafb9b058 id: nil, user_id: nil, location: "New York", description: "something somethings", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

As you can see above the parameters are being passed but not the id and the user_id is nil as well, is it because of the association that is not being built?

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @photos = Photo.all
  end

  def show
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
    if @photo.save
      redirect_to @photo
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.update(photo_params)
        format
          .html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(
      :location,
      :description,
      :image,
    )
  end
end
```

Here is the controller for Photos. Here I have new and create. In `create` I'm passing the params to create the photo. I wonder if I should pass this from the current user due to the following association.

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :photos
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

Here I have that the following models. A user has many photos and a photo belongs to the user.

```
class CreatePhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :photos do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.string :location
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

As far as the migration for photos goes. I don't think I have to add `:image` to the table since ActiveStorage takes care of that by the `has_one_attached` method. Not sure what the issue is?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, include the text itself in your question. You also need to show what `photo_params` contains, we can't comment meaningfully based on the single snippet of code posted.

Comment: fair enough, will update post.

Comment: @meagar changes made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [default options](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#optional) of

```
belongs_to :user
```

require the `user_id` to be set in current versions of Rails. Because you do not assign a user to the new photo the photo cannot be saved.

To assign the current user to a new photo just change this line

```
@photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
```

in your `create` method in the controller to

```
@photo = current_user.photos.build(photo_params)
```

I advise reading the docs about the [`has_many` association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) in the Rails Guides.

Comment: `@photo = current_user.photos.build(photo_params)` didn't work but `@photo = current_user.photos.create(photo_params)` did. Why was that?

Comment: `build` return nils for id and timestamps in contrast to `create`

Comment: Sure, `build` only initializes the record but doesn't save the record to the database. Btw, therefore, the id and timestamps are still `nil`. In the next line, you call `if @photo.save` which will then persist the record into the database and then your record will have an id and the timestamps set.

Answer (score 0):

Your `photo_params` contains only three values:

```
    params.require(:photo).permit(
      :location,
      :description,
      :image,
    )
```

Those are the only values you're passing to `Photo.new`, so those are the only fields that are being populated. It's unclear why you would expect the `user_id` to be set, but the `id` and `created_at` fields are populated automatically when you `save` the record. Put your `binding.pry` *after* your `save` call.

Comment: So im missing the `user_id` param. I see